# Copy Hbase data to Existing Table

Tags: hbase

I know how to do it by Java code. I would like to know is there any way to do from Hbase shell.

I tried Snapshots, CopyTable. But both expects new destination table but not existing table.

I need to blindly copy all the rows from source table to destination table. If destination table has that row key, it has to update. It should not overwrite non-existing rows.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to get clarity on the question.. This data is being tried to copy within the same cluster or different HBase cluster? This copy should be done for existing data or it should be done for incoming new data also?

Comment: Only Existing Data. Same cluster

Comment: As far as I know, this can't be achieved using any option provided by HBase. As you said your own Java code is the only viable option.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the the mapreduce import/ export to copy data between two existing tables.